# Why doesn't my GPU work for my mac?

Tags: rendering, gpu, osx

### Mac info:

iMac (27-inch, Late 2013)

3.2 GHz Intel Core i5

8 GB 1600 MHz DDR3

NVIDIA GeForce GT 755M 1024 MB

---

Every time I try to render using my GPU, it crashes, hopefully some of you can give me some good advice, also I've tried going to Nvidia website but they don't have my graphic info so I can't get CUDA (NVIDIA GeForce GT 755M 1024 MB). Is there any other way I can get my GPU to work?

Thank you guys.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this appears to be at its root, a question about hardware, not about Blender. To that end, I'd suggest that the question be asked on the sister Stack Echange site, [hardwarerecs.stackexchange](http://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Agrade, welcome to the site. I invite you to take the [tour](http://blender.stackexchange.com/tour/), and review the [help center](http://blender.stackexchange.com/help/), especially those parts relating to what kinds of questions to ask, and what kinds not to ask.

Comment: The M series of Nvidia GPUS is not very powerful... The iMac is nothing else than an oversized, non portable laptop...  My guess is that the GPU is already using a lot of its resources (vRAM) to display things on the screen. With only I gig of vRAM you are possibly overtaxing the resources available on your system.

Comment: Totally agree with @cegaton Your graphics card is not designed for "3D hard work" You have only 1GB of memory. System take about 200-700 MB (depend of settings and running applications)  so not much remain for Blender. Your hardware is not good for 3D, that's all :-(

Comment: Thank you for answering my question guys,is there any way i can upgrade it? so i could use it for 3D hard work?

Comment: @Agrade hardware recommendations are not within the scope of this site. try: http://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/

Comment: The imacs and macbooks can't upgrade more than RAM and HD. You could google "cycles render farm" or look at [creating your own render farm](https://cgcookie.com/tutorial/setting-up-a-renderfarm/) to do your rendering.

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure you have installed the CUDA driver for your mac:
http://www.nvidia.com/object/mac-driver-archive.html

I have a 750M in my MacBook Pro (2.8 GHz Intel Core i7) and it renders about as fast as the CPU as long as the render job's RAM requirement doesn't exceed the RAM on the video card. In fact, I often render overnight with both CPU and GPU concurrently as separate command lines.